# OverflowError cannot fit int into an index-sized integer

Tags: python-3.x

Hello Guys I am new to the python, I am learning the basic & during my practice i found one Issue

****(OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer)****

Below are my Code

```
# Ask user their details & Age Information

userName = input("What is your name? ")
userAge = input("What is your age? ")

userAgeInt = int(userAge)

print ("Hello there"  + userName)

userAgeTenTime = (userAge * 10)

userAgeTenTimeInt = int(userAgeTenTime)

print ("Your Age ten times is" * userAgeTenTimeInt )

if(userAgeInt >= 18):
   print('You are old enough to vote')

else:
    print('You are not old enough to vote')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with these 3 lines:

```
userAgeTenTime = (userAge * 10)
userAgeTenTimeInt = int(userAgeTenTime)
print ("Your Age ten times is" * userAgeTenTimeInt )
```

Here, you take the `userAge` string, let's say `"123"` and repeat it 10 times - `"123123123123123123123123123123"`

Then you convert it into an integer (`123123123123123123123123123123`).

Then you try to repeat the string `"Your Age ten times is"`, 123123123123123123123123123123 times.

I believe your intention was:

```
userAgeTenTime = (userAgeInt * 10)
print ("Your Age ten times is", userAgeTenTime)
```